# Formatting JSON to allow multiple elements?

Tags: json

I am trying to pass the below JSON but the endpoint is rejecting it, it doesn't like the "multiple elements". What am I doing wrong ? I am assuming that I am being an idiot here ( new to JSON and API stuff ).

```
{"affiliationKey": "CLNT","relationshipKey": "Customer"},{"affiliationKey": "CLAS","relationshipKey": "Customer"},{"affiliationKey": "CTOB","relationshipKey": "Customer"},{"affiliationKey": "CTPT","relationshipKey": "Customer"},{"affiliationKey": "CTAS","relationshipKey": "Customer"},{"affiliationKey": "NONE","relationshipKey": "Customer"},{"affiliationKey": "OTHR","relationshipKey": "Customer"}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear!

Comment: First of all check the API documentation in what format the data is required. Does it work for multiple elements or not? If it works then probably you need to pass an array. Just put the whole thing in between square brackets... `[{"affiliationKey": "CLNT","relationshipKey": "Customer"}, {},...]`